# MVVMCross Get current item in MvxListView

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-alertdialog

I display a list of posts and if I click on the edit button in the post an alert dialog pop for editing the post.

I try to bind the current item when I click on a button in my list view, but i don't know how to access to it.

This is my code :

ViewModel

```
private Post _theCurrentPost;

public Post TheCurrentPost
{
    get { return _theCurrentPost; }
    set
    {
      _theCurrentPost = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => TheCurrentPost);
    }
}
private MvxCommand _openEditDialog;
public ICommand OpenEditDialog
{
   get
   {
     _openShareDialog = _openShareDialog ?? new MvxCommand(LoadCurrentSharedPost);
     return _openShareDialog;
   }
}
private void LoadCurrentSharedPost(Post cur)
{
   TheSharedPost = cur;
}
```

Main.xmla

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource PostsList; ItemClick ShowDetails"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/posttemplate" />
</LinearLayout>
```

PostTemplate.xmla

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/fond_post"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text Title"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text Content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Edit"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            local:MvxBind="Click OpenEditDialog"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does someone know how to send the current item in the binding ?
And could I launch an alert dialog from the ViewModel or I have to create a onclick method in the code behind.

Thanks.

Comment: `OpenEditDialog` will be a command within your list item viewmodel - i.e. within your `Post` - so it will already know which `Post` is being edited?

Comment: I think I found my error : I can't access to the ViewModel in the template so I have to pass it with a MvxMessage like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535943/bind-button-click-inside-customlayout-using-mvvmcross-and-mvxlistview . Is it correct ?

Comment: @MaxDOT that depends. If your command is being handled in the child  ViewModel, then as Stuart says, you have access to it already, since you're in the context of the Post. However, my answer (that your linked) is when you want to handle the command in a parent ViewModel. That's where MvxMessenger comes in handy.

Comment: My command has to be handled in the parent ViewModel, so I will use MvxMessenger. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the ListItem as a parameter you have to use a "." , as for the binding button question here is another post of the same topic [Using MvxCommand With CommandParameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234539/using-mvxcommand-with-commandparameter-binding) according to it you just have to add CommandParameter , in the end it would look something like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Edit"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    local:MvxBind="Click OpenEditDialog, CommandParameter=."
    android:background="@drawable/edit_button" />
```

Yes you can launch an alert dialog from the ViewModel. If you are planning on creating other projects using MvvmCross, I would suggest you create a plugin for your application that contains this service, if you do not know about plugins you can check here http://slodge.blogspot.fr/2012/10/build-new-plugin-for-mvvmcrosss.html or look for it online. As for the code it would look like this:

```
//This goes in core
public interface IAlertService
{
    void CreateAlert(string title, string messagem, etc...);
}

//This goes in droid
public class AlertService : IAlertService
{
    public void CreateAlert(string title, string messagem, etc...)
    {
          //Android code for creating AlertDialog
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying the same `local:MvxBind="Click OpenEditDialog, CommandParameter=."` I'm getting the same "." while executing commmand. any idea please?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778749/mvxtabsfragment-failed-to-create-target-binding-for-binding-command-for/22779090#22779090